# Thread synchronisation

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

We have two methods

```
A(){
....//A-method body
}
B(){
....//B-method body
}
```

Task is to synchronize them in such way:
In any order of starting threads Method A should wait until Method B is finished.
Assume we have standard synchronisation objects - Mutex,Semphore,Monitor.
How can this be implemented?
**Update 1**
I've tried this.

```
Mutex mut = new Mutex();

A(){
    mut.Lock();
    ....//A-method body
    mut.Release();
}
B(){
    mut.Lock();
    ....//B-method body
    mut.Release();
}
```

But the problem is that in such implementation there is posibility that method B will be executed first.
I want **A** always wait till **B** will be finished

Comment: any specific language?

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far, and what results that gave you?

Comment: To answer with the same specificity with which you asked: You must wait on some object at the beginning of method A, and signal it at the end of method B.

Comment: @big_buka any problems with the answer as why below answer is not marked as accepted answer ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is normally accomplished with events or semaphores. A semaphore is created externally to threads A and B, B sets a semaphore at the end, and A waits for a semaphore to signal.

If you don't need/want to use synchronization primitives, it would be enough to use a global boolean variable and check it in a loop in thread A (but of course this will not be as effective as a synchro object).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAVA then you can go for countdown latch

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
A(){
latch.await();
....//A-method body
}
B(){
....//B-method body
latch.countDown();
}
```